# c# (ado) alter table add column - give a name to a column from a variable (Datetime)

Tags: c#, sql

This my code:

```cs
string myDate = dateTime.Month.ToString() + "/" + dateTime.Year.ToString();
sqlCommand.CommandText = ("ALTER TABLE working_hours ADD "+ myDate  +" float ");
```

It doesn't work. But if I replace the Date value with something else then everything works

```cs
//*string myDate="DateTime";
```

I have to get a new column named date (month/year) -> 11/20 10/20 09/20.

Comment: Obviously it is a very bad idea to put a column named `11/20`. Also it is not allowed to use a number for the first character of a column name. C1 is Ok but 1C is not. You may try to put a prefix to your column name like `C11/20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - I'd highly suggest against this kind of data model. It's going to be hard to scale it. However if you insist of doing so, the issue is generated SQL statement. I assume you're using SQL Server and this would be the statement it generates:

```sql
ALTER TABLE working_hours ADD 11/20 float
```

Which is incorrect, identifiers in SQL Server, that have illegal characters, must be wrapped in square brackets.

```sql
ALTER TABLE working_hours ADD [11/20] FLOAT;
```

So this should work:

```cs
string myDate = dateTime.Month.ToString() + "/" + dateTime.Year.ToString();
sqlCommand.CommandText = ("ALTER TABLE working_hours ADD [" + myDate + "] FLOAT;");
```

But again - I'd highly suggest against this kind of design. Create a dedicated table with a normalized date field. It's going to be easier to query and maintain that kind of structure.